# Laravel - An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions

Tags: php, laravel, azure, sockets, redis

I am hosting a Laravel web app on Azure. All the pages works fine on localhost and even on Azure. But there is one page that gives me an error:

> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its
>   access permissions. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

What could be the reason? The error occurs when I view an item with id. The id is being fetched from the database.

The function where the error occurs:

```
protected function onConnectionError($message, $code = null)
    {
        CommunicationException::handle(
            new ConnectionException($this, static::createExceptionMessage($message), $code)
        );
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Quick observation: port 6379 is Redis.

Comment: @JohnEllmore Yes, it's the default port for redis. I changed the port to something else in my .env file but it still didn't work.

Comment: This sounds like a firewall issue. It's weird that it's affecting 127.0.0.1 though.

Comment: @JohnEllmore Are you saying it shouldn't be 127.0.0.1? What should the redis host be then?

Comment: No, 127.0.0.1 is fine, assuming that Laravel and Redis are on the same box. It's just weird that the firewall is blocking communication over the loopback address.

Comment: @JohnEllmore I know. I am stuck with this issue since 4 days. Do you know any solution?

Comment: Where is the code running? Azure Web Apps? VMs? Where is Redis hosted?

Comment: @Qualcuno Azure Web Apps. I didn't create any Redis server. The .env file shows 127.0.0.1

Comment: then that's your problem... You don't have any Redis server and the module is expecting one to connect to.